# In Rails should i generate a model to contain simple plain list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently building a web-page with Ruby on Rails. Im creating A data model that works as follows: Project has many Milestones and milestone has many goals

Example:

```
Project.milestones.goals
```

So I generated a model for Project and a model for milestones but generating a model for list of goals seems like big and unnecessary.

Should I generate a model for goals or is there something else that would fit more for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to this question: Goals need to be persisted on your database?
If the answer is yes, then you must create a model that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`, and if the answer is no, you could create a model, that don't have the need for persistence methods of `ActiveRecord`, but acts like an `Enum`, having static values and stuff.

Comment: It seems like so much over head to do so... what if every goal has a title and another list ? then I would generate another model?

Comment: and yeah everything should be persistent

Comment: Well, if you think that it is overhead, you can try approach the problem from a different angle. Maybe reducing the needs for a different table on you database, or making a table with more values than usual so you can have fewer joins. The bottom line is that it all comes down to your design choice. =]

Comment: Well thanks :) I guess I need some more experience with database to know how to create more efficient designs